# How do I find the applications that require the .NET framework?

Tags: c#, .net-framework

Is there a way to look at all the applications installed on a users computer and determine which, if any, are utilizing the .NET framework? My problem is that I want to upgrade our users computers from .NET 4.0 to 4.5. In order to do this I am required to also re-test all the installed applications that are built for 4.0. I know that it is backward compatible and a 4.0 application should run fine on 4.5 but I can't get away with that statement alone. And nobody can tell me why 4.0 was even put onto the computers so I don't know if any of the applications that are currently there require it. I don't have the capability to uninstall 4.0 and run all the applications to see which ones fail either. Any suggestions? Are there tools I can use to look at all the applications?

Comment: Asked before: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2080046/how-to-check-if-a-program-is-using-net

Comment: The .NET frameworks can be installed side-by-side. So you can leave .NET 4.0 and install .NET 4.5 next to. The applications will load the required runtime version. I see no need to ininstall .NET 4.0 unless I misunderstand your question.

Comment: I didn't realize the 4.0 and 4.5 sit side by side. I thought that 4.5 replaced 4.0 as an update to it. This makes things much easier for me. This solves my problem. Thanks.

Comment: @Ben : you didn't realize 4.0 and 4.5 could sit side by side because they can't. It's an in-place update. See this post for all the compatibility issues you may encounter: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dotnet/archive/2011/09/26/compatibility-of-net-framework-4-5.aspx

Comment: @Falanwe: Good find. You learn something every day :-)

Comment: Thank you for confirming. I thought 4.5 was an update but there is a lot I don't know so I wasn't sure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like [Hans Passant's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3742534/632736) answer may provide some assistance. Essentially he explains how to write a script to enumerate all executables and determine which version of .NET, if any, they require.

<del>Jakob's right though. There's no need to uninstall 4.0 when the frameworks [can run side by side](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8477k21c.aspx) without negative impact.</del> Thanks Falanwe.

Comment: .Net 4.0 and .Net 4.5 cannot run side-by-side, they share the same version number! See this post for détails: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dotnet/archive/2011/09/26/compatibility-of-net-framework-4-5.aspx

Comment: Thanks Falanwe! Do you know if all minor framework upgrades are in-place updates?